# Differences between python 2.7 and 2.4 produce an Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.4

I've been posting on here for a while trying to find the reason for my invisible python problems.  Locally, my script runs fine, but when I upload it, it only executes halfway.

My python script generates an html file.  I have cron-jobbed the python script so that my file gets updated every few minutes.  However, it was only creating the first few lines of code and stopping.

I believe the reason to be (after some investigation) that my server is running Python 2.4 and I am running 2.7.  However, I'm not sure how to upgrade (downgrade?) my script into 2.4.I think it is just one line of code that is the bane of my existence.

Here is the relevant code:

phones.py: This calls the other file SearchPhone and generates the html into celly.html

```
from SearchPhone import SearchPhone

phones = ["iphone 4", "iphone 5", "iphone 3"]
f = open('celly.html','w')


f.write("""<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Celly Blue Book</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
""")

#table
f.write('<table width="100%" border="1">')
for x in phones:
    print "Pre-Searchphone DEBUG" ##THIS PRINTS!!

    y = SearchPhone(x)  ## <--Here is the culprit.  

    print "Post-SearchPhone DEBUG" ##THIS DOES NOT!!

    f.write( "\t<tr>")
    f.write( "\t\t<td>" + str(y[0]) + "</td>")
    f.write( "\t\t<td>" + str(y[1]) + "</td>")
    f.write( "\t\t<td>" + str(y[2]) + "</td>")
    f.write( "\t\t<td>" + str(y[3]) + "</td>")
    f.write( "\t\t<td>" + str(y[4]) + "</td>")
    f.write( "\t</tr>")

f.write('</table>')

f.close()
```

SearchPhone.py: This searches for the phone and is called by phones.py

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

def SearchPhone(phone):

    y = "http://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/moa?query=" + phone + "+-%22buy%22+-%22fix%22+-%22unlock%22+-%22broken%22+-%22cracked%22+-%22parts%22&srchType=T&minAsk=&maxAsk="

    site = urllib.urlopen(y)
    html = site.read()
    site.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


    prices = soup.findAll("span", {"class":"itempp"})
    prices = [str(j).strip('<span class="itempp"> $</span>') for j in prices]

    for k in prices[:]:
        if k == '': #left price blank
            prices.remove(k)
        elif int(k) <= 75: #less than $50: probably a service (or not true)
            prices.remove(k)
        elif int(k) >= 999: #probably not true
            prices.remove(k)

    #Find Average Price
    intprices = []
    newprices = prices[:]
    total = 0
    for k in newprices:
        total += int(k)
        intprices.append(int(k))

    intprices = sorted(intprices)

    try:
        del intprices[0]
        del intprices[-1]


        avg = total/len(newprices)
        low = intprices[0]
        high = intprices[-1]

        if len(intprices) % 2 == 1:
            median = intprices[(len(intprices)+1)/2-1]
        else:
            lower = intprices[len(intprices)/2-1]
            upper = intprices[len(intprices)/2]
            median = (float(lower + upper)) / 2  



        namestr = str(phone)
        medstr = "Median: $" + str(median)
        avgstr = "Average: $" + str(avg)
        lowstr = "Low: $" + str(intprices[0])
        highstr = "High: $" + str(intprices[-1])
        samplestr = "# of samples: " + str(len(intprices))
        linestr = "-------------------------------"

    except IndexError:
        namestr = str(phone)
        medstr = "N/A"
        avgstr = "N/A"
        lowstr = "N/A"
        highstr = "N/A"
        samplestr = "N/A"
        linestr = "-------------------------------"

    return (namestr, medstr, avgstr, lowstr, highstr, samplestr, linestr)
```

HERE IS THE TRACEBACK:

```
Pre-SearchPhone DEBUG
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tseymour/public_html/celly/phones.py", line 35, in ?
    y = SearchPhone(x)
  File "/home/tseymour/public_html/celly/SearchPhone.py", line 11, in SearchPhone
    site = urllib.urlopen(y)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib.py", line 82, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib.py", line 190, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib.py", line 322, in open_http
    return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib.py", line 339, in http_error
    return self.http_error_default(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib.py", line 579, in http_error_default
    return addinfourl(fp, headers, "http:" + url)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib.py", line 883, in __init__
    addbase.__init__(self, fp)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib.py", line 830, in __init__
    self.read = self.fp.read
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Thanks for all the help guys.

Tyler

Comment: Jeez just a few more rep points and I can offer a bounty.

Comment: If your deployment platform is stuck at Python 2.4, why not install the same version on your development platform (both to debug this issue, and to use for development going forward)?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so urllib2 has the same problem...  Looking more closely at the error report, I see that it is trying to handle an error.  Line 322 of urllib.py  Try using wget or similar to make sure that you can access the URL you're trying to from the server.  If you can, copy urllib to someplace you can edit it that is on the pythonpath and add some debugging information to figure out why it thinks there is an error.  Since I can't seem to reproduce the problem on 2.4, and 2.4 is long out of service, you're going to need to track down what is going on in order to fix it.  My guess is that `fp` on line 322 is supposed to get set to self.fp, but I don't know if it defaults to None and is not getting set, or if it is getting a None passed in.  Also, what minor version of python2.4 are you running?  I've got 2.4.3, if you like, I can make the urllib.py from my install available and you can run a diff to see if there is a difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

I changed over to Pythonwhere.com, NO PROBLEMS!